# jQuery set iFrame onLoad attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to trigger a function when the iframe loads a second time (the user clicks some link in the iframe). When the iframe page changes I can set the window location to the iframe src.

What I thought would be best is to set an onLoad attribute on the iframe element after the first load. I guess I would need the live event to tell when the iframe has been created, since it's dynamic.

This is what I had in mind:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tenant_login').fancybox({type:'iframe'});
    $('#tenant_login').click(function() {
        $('#fancybox-frame').attr('onload', function() {
            window.location = $('#fancybox-iframe').attr('src');
        });
    });
});
```

If it matters the iframe is not cross domain.

Comment: "onload" should be lowercase.

Comment: You are trying to have users click around on some other web page via an iframe, then at some point, wherever they are, redirect them to that same URL in a regular window?

Comment: @Andy Atkinson Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do. What I noticed is the src of the iframe never changes.

I just used a target="_top" attribute on the particular link I wanted to open in a regular window it solved the problem. I guess I could bind an event to the iframes DOM somehow, but "_top" was easier.

Comment: Hey Keyo, can you explain how you solved your problem and mark your answer as accepted? This is drawing a lot of traffic and Googles fairly highly for iframe onload related problems — it'd be good to see the solution!

Comment: I've added an answer. I think Stefan's answer is probably more useful for solving the original question I asked.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#fancybox-iframe").load(function(){
            window.location = $('#fancybox-iframe').attr('src');
});
```

This will allow you to redirect the parent window when the iframe loads a different page.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the iframe content, as I did setting a `target="_top"` attribute on the hyperlink means the browser will open the link in the browser window rather than the iframe.

Main document:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <h1>The Main Page</h1>
     <iframe src="myIframe.html" />
  </body>
<html>
```

Iframe document:

```
<h2>The IFRAME</h2>
<a href="something.html" target="_top" >
  This will open in the browser window rather than any iframe it exists in.
</a>
```

If you can't put `target="_top"` on the links of the iframe DOM you will need to capture the click events with javascript from the parent DOM.